# How does this ANTLR 3 convert to ANTLR4?

Tags: parsing, antlr4, antlr3

This is ANTLR 3 grammar. How does it convert to ANTLR 4? The carat is a problem?

```
text_string_no_linebreak:
    text_string -> ^(STRING_NO_LINEBREAK_TOKEN text_string)
;
```

**no viable alternative at character '^'**

Here's another one that gives the same error:

```
create_index: // For external use only. Don't reference this in the normal grammar.
    CREATE_SYMBOL^ create_index_tail SEMICOLON_SYMBOL? EOF
;
```

Comment: Just remove it: it is no longer supported.

Comment: All of them? All contexts?

Comment: Yes, embedded carets like this `foo : Foo^ bar;` can simply be removed. And in rewrite rules like this: `foo : Foo bar -> ^(Foo bar);` everything from the arrow (`->`) can be removed, leaving only `foo : Foo bar;`. Also checkout the Q&A I linked to.

Comment: What Q&A? I don't see it.

Comment: In the yellow-ish box that was added to your question after I closed it :)

Comment: What about the ! operator? What happens to that in ANTLR 4?

Comment: All tree operators (`^`, `!`, `->`) are no longer supported.

Comment: What about the + operator ? Is that supported?

routine_create_options:
 routine_create_option+ 
;

Comment: Check yourself here: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#subrules and https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexer-rule-elements